# How can I turn Ethernet extension into a WiFi Hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, hotspot

I have a long house with thick brick walls. The router is at one end of the house and the WiFi does not reach the rear rooms. I do have a hardwired Ethernet connection running to the back of the property with an Ethernet splitter attached.

Is there any type of device/dongle I can attach to the splitter that would transmit a WiFi signal that could be picked up by mobile phones etc? I'm not very computer savvy and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Is the ethernet cable attached to the router? Usually, you would install a WLAN access point (AP) at the other end of the ethernet cable (in the back of the property). What do you mean by "ethernet splitter"? A regular switch or something else?

Comment: The router connects to a WLAN access point at the front of the house. A cable then runs beneath the floorboards to the rear wall of the house where there is another access point. I've just looked it up and I've actually connected a 5 port ethernet desktop switch. Can I plug anything into one of the switch ports to transmit WiFi to mobile phones and my printer? Thank you

Comment: I think I've been using the word "router" when i meant "modem." So, 'phone line' to 'modem' to 'long ,underfloor ethernet cable' to 'acccess point on wall' to 'ethernet switch.'  Modem transmits Wifi to front of house only. There is nowhere to put a plug in WiFi extender in the middle, even if the Wifi reached that far. How can I get wifi at the back of the house preferably from the switch? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Have you considered a mesh Wi-Fi system or Wi-Fi extender?

Comment: The whole thing is a little confusing, could you make a diagram of how everything is connected to each other (including the layout of the house)? Neither a Modem nor a switch does transmit a WLAN (or Wifi) signal. The usual setup is that a modem transmits a PPPoE signal which is connected to a router, which is connected to a switch which connects to other devices (PCs, switches, APs). In most cases, modem, router, switch and access point are integrated into one device mostly referred to as "router" (although it's much more than a router).

Comment: Assuming you setup is Modem/Router <-- Ethenet cable --> AP (front) <-- Ethenet cable --> Switch (back). Or do you have two APs? In case of my assumtion you just need to plug another AP into the switch and set up the WLAN on the new AP and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, for your time everyone. I think I need an access point. I've just Googled access points and realised that was what I needed. Just ordered one along with a WiFi dongle for my PC. I know it sounds stupid but I thought the access point was the thing that looks like a white light switch on the wall (but with a port where the switch should be) at either end of the data cable under the floor where i plug in the ethernet cable - didn't realise it was a totally different piece of hardware. Well, I've learned something today. Happy New Year

Comment: Glad we could help. If possible make sure that the new access point is compatible to the existing one (the one that already gives you WiFi), which means same Frequency and same encryption etc. This way you're device will roam more "smoothly". By the way, was my new interpretation correct? `Multipurpose Device (Modem/Router/AP/Switch) (front)` `<-- Ethernet cable -->` `Switch (back)`

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look for an access point, and based off your description, not a PoE one.

Comment: How does the OP do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend replacing the ethernet splitter with a switch, it is really not recommended to use hubs and splitters. Then you can run ethernet lines from the switch and connect them to access points like @JCA122204 said.

Ubiquiti has really good prices on their products and their products are really good, their products are used for businesses that cannot afford or do not want to purchase overpriced cisco equipment.

Comment: Thanks. I have realised I do actually have a working 5 port switch already in use at the rear of the house. What hardware would I connect to one of those ports to transmit WiFi to mobile phones and my printer?I know I sound stupid but I have no idea what anything is called.

Comment: You will need an access point along with an ethernet cord for each access point you setup.

Comment: Thanks, I've just Googled it and realised what an access point actually is. You're right. Happy New Year

Comment: Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

I've added a diagram of what I think your current setup looks like, and what you need to add labelled in red:

[image]

The red square represents your house, and the blue ovals represent your WiFi coverage areas (where you can get a WiFi connection on your devices). Currently, you only have one WiFi router, meaning you have only the bottom oval that covers half your house. Myself and the community here are suggesting you add a second wifi access point to give you the second oval and provide WiFi across the whole house.

The easiest way to do this is to buy another router such as [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-Archer-C1200-External-Antennas/dp/B0743HB9H2/ref=sr_1_12?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1546635281&sr=1-12&keywords=wireless+ac+router) and connect an ethernet cable from it to the current router in the house. Make sure the new router is on the opposite side of the house to the current one.

It will need to be in **Access Point Mode**, which is a setting you can change following the instructions [here](https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-2066.html). I appreciate these are still a little technical, so if you don't have help available in person I am happy to provide further advice.

Comment: It would be nice if you would give me a chance to write an answer myself before you take my suggestion from the comments to write you're own answer.

Comment: besides that, it's most likely he/she already has a router in the setup since she seems to connect multiple devices, in this case buying a second router is unnecessary (in fact it will cause problems if it introduces a second DHCP server).

Comment: @Albin He posted his posted his post before you. Quit being so hostile for some karma....

Comment: @MatthewValdez that is not correct, I posted my solution (to add another AP) a few hours ago, it was the very first comment. Besides, what gives you the impression I'm being hostile? I'm just asking nicely for fair conduct?!?

Comment: @Albin: You had 8 hours to write that answer before this one was posted, I think that's fairly reasonable. Most people here on site _never_ bother to expand their semi-answer "comments" themselves, indeed it usually seems as if they expect someone else to post one (and officially comments are for asking the OP for clarification, _not_ for providing a semi-answer). If you still have a better one, then you can still write a better one.

Comment: @grawity might be, but most users with a high volume of participation on SU consider a "grace period" for 1-2 days or asking if the author of the comment to use the solution in one's own answer (I asked that very question in meta a while ago, those were the answers). Anyway, I'm planning on writing an answer (as soon as the necessary info is available), that's why I ask that question in the first place, didn't mean to be rude, just wanted to make a polite notification.

Comment: Well, now you know, that I want to expand the answer in my comment into a regular as soon as my question is answered, please be considerate of that. Thanks.

Comment: In regards to you're answer: I don't like your implications ("as a digital consultant..."), I think it's rather rude. That being said, unfortunately, you are wrong. You are confusing with an actual "router" with a multipurpose device that includes a router and an AP. Which is often (but incorrectly) referred to as "router" by most non-technical users. Yes, an integrated DHCP-server (most times) can be disabled, but if it's not it causes problems when a second DHCP-server is connected as well.That's why I used the word "IF"). And a multipurpose device is usually more expensive than a single AP.

Comment: That's why it would be important to clarify the question before writing a (possibly) wrong answer and giving wrong advice, especially with a "not very computer savvy" person. That's the reason why I still waited with my answer. Anyway don't be offended, as I said, this was just meant as a polite notification. Now that you know I would suggest deleting all the off-topic comments?!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your latest comments, your setup is as follows:

`Multipurpose Device (Modem/Router/AP/Switch) (front)` `<--Ethernet cable-->` `Switch (back)`

(and you have an existing WiFi setup)

In this case, you will just need an AP which will be connected to the switch in the back (as you already realized correctly according to your last comment).

If possible make sure that the new access point is compatible to the existing one (the one that already gives you WiFi, regardless if it's integrated in the multipurpose device or if it's a separate device), which means same frequency and same encryption etc. This way you're device will roam more "smoothly" between the APs in the front and in the back. When you set up the AP make sure to use the same SSID and the same password as you use for your existing WiFi. If you don't know if your Multipurpose Device / Switch supports PoE (power over ethernet) make sure to get an AP without PoE (one that provides a power supply you can plug into a power outlet).

Some PCs already have WiFi integrated, you might want to check that before you buy an extra "WiFi dongle". You also can connect the PC via another cable if it has a network card to the switch in the back or the multipurpose device in the front.

Also note: if you only connect the AP to the switch in the back, you can just disconnect the switch altogether and connect the AP directly with the ethernet cable. This way it will save you a little power consumption.